# How to set env variable in Heroku with Node.js? how to do that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, environment-variables

I am trying to set an environment variable for socks proxy. This variable is dependent on ip and port. i.e. socks://23.244.534.344:8080 Issue is that in Heroku the port is dynamic. Unfortunately I cannot do this dynamically in my Node code as I need it in a public module. So ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku doesn't allow you to setup a port. But there are options available for you to add a SOCKS proxy as a Heroku add-on. One of a such kind is called [Fixie Socks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fixie-socks). You can set a proxy PORT there and it will help you deploy